# Searching for adverse reports related to quality only reported in 2017

Tags: api, openfda

I'm trying to search for the number of adverse reports related to "quality" within the query and only for the year 2017.  I've tried this query
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:[20170101+TO+20171231]+AND+patient.reaction.reactionmedrapt:%22quality%22

and several others but everything I've done comes up with 0 results and I know there are some within 2017.  I'd like to get down to be able to identify down to pharm_class_epc:"vaccine" ,"protein", "peptide", and others also.

But any help with constructing this query to pull data from 2017 first would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have a minor typo in the field name, i.e. `reactionmedrapt` should be `reactionmeddrapt`. After correcting the query returns results as expected: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:[20170101+TO+20171231]+AND+patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt:%22quality%22